# Kafka Connect failing to read from Kafka topics over SSL

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Running kafka connect in our docker-swarm, with the following compose file:

```
cp-kafka-connect-node:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.1.0
    ports:
      - 28085:28085
    secrets:
      - kafka.truststore.jks
      - source: kafka-connect-aws-credentials
        target: /root/.aws/credentials
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka01:9093,kafka02:9093,kafka03:9093
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LEVEL: TRACE
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 28085
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: cp-kafka-connect
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: dev_cp-kafka-connect-config
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: dev_cp-kafka-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: dev_cp-kafka-connect-status
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE: 'false'
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE: 'false'
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: /usr/share/java/
      CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SSL
      CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: /run/secrets/kafka.truststore.jks
      CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: ********
      KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS: '-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=2'
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 4gb
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 10s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 2000s

secrets:
  kafka.truststore.jks:
    external: true
  kafka-connect-aws-credentials:
    external: true
```

The kafka connect node starts up successfully, and I am able to set up tasks and view the status of those tasks...

The connector I setup I called kafka-sink, I created it with the following config:

```
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
    "s3.region": "eu-central-1",
    "flush.size": "1",
    "schema.compatibility": "NONE",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "input-topic-name",
    "s3.part.size": "5242880",
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "directory.delim": "/",
    "locale": "UK",
    "s3.compression.type": "gzip",
    "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.bytearray.ByteArrayFormat",
    "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner",
    "schema.generator.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator",
    "name": "kafka-sink",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
    "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
    "s3.bucket.name": "my-s3-bucket",
    "rotate.schedule.interval.ms": "60000"
  }
```

This task now says that it is running.

When I did not include the SSL config, specifically:

```
  CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka01:9093,kafka02:9093,kafka03:9093
  CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SSL
  CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: /run/secrets/kafka.truststore.jks
  CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: ********
```

and instead pointed to a bootstrap server that was exposed with no security:

```
  CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: insecurekafka:9092
```

It worked fine, and read from the appropriate input topic, and output to the S3 bucket with default partitioning...

However, when I run it using the SSL config against my secure kafka topic, it logs no errors, throws no exceptions, but does nothing at all despite data continuously being pushed to the input topic...

Am I doing something wrong?

This is my first time using Kafka Connect, normally, I connect to kafka using Spring Boot apps where you just have to specify the truststore location and password in the config.

Am I missing some configuration in either my compose file or my task config?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to add SSL config for both consumer and producer. Check here [Kafka Connect Encrypt with SSL](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/encryption.html#encryption-ssl-connect)
Something like this

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=~/kafka.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=<password>
ssl.keystore.location=~/kafka.client.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=<password>
ssl.key.password=<password>

producer.security.protocol=SSL
producer.ssl.truststore.location=~/kafka.truststore.jks
producer.ssl.truststore.password=<password>
producer.ssl.keystore.location=~/kafka.client.keystore.jks
producer.ssl.keystore.password=<password>
producer.ssl.key.password=<password>
```

Comment: Brilliant! This solved my issue!

I added:

`CONNECT_PRODUCER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SSL
CONNECT_PRODUCER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: /run/secrets/kafka.truststore.jks
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: ********
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SSL
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: /run/secrets/kafka.truststore.jks
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: ********`


and now it is working! :)

Comment: Thank you soo much! It took me days to find this as well! I was using only `CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL`, `CONNECT_KEYSTORE_LOCATION`... and it turns out we also need to define the producer specific configuration `CONNECT_PRODUCER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL`, `CONNECT_PRODUCER_KEYSTORE_LOCATION`... otherwise it fails to produce to topics